# Batch File to restart the service after reading value

Tags: batch-file

I am using Windows Server 2003.
Here is the scenario;

text file name "abc.txt" in this file I have a value xyz = 2 on third line, I want a batch script who check this value from third line and if it goes above 10 then it will restart "asd" service.

I think i describe what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%G IN ('find "xyz =" ^<abc.txt') DO set xyz=%%G

IF %xyz% gtr 10 (
net stop servicename
net start servicename
)
```